# Can it be done without useImperativeHandle hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

As mentioned in react docs that **useImperativeHandle** hook lets you expose selective functions/funtionality when passing a ref to child component (such as exposing focus but not blur)

I tried and achieved the same functionality without **useImperativeHandle** hook.
Can anyone please explain why we even need **useImperativeHandle** hook then.

Here is a link to the code sandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-matsumoto-blci8?file=/src/App.js

Also here is an state full version of the same.
https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-borg-zknpg?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that your version doesn't do. First, here are some things you're missing, but you could kinda add an equivalent for by adding some more code:

- refs aren't always objects, they can also be functions. So you would need to check the type on the ref, and either call the ref, or set .current on it as appropriate.
- useImperativeHandle lets you provide a dependency array, so you don't create a new value unless you need to. You could mimic this by using useMemo.
- When a component unmounts, its ref normally gets nulled out, but yours doesn't do that. You'd need to add a `useEffect` with a teardown function to get that behavior

But then there's one which you have no possible way to address: timing. Normally, components render first, then refs get populated/nulled, then effects get run. But your approach cannot replicate that. The ref will get populated before rendering is complete, and if you add the code to null out the ref, that will happen when effects are run.

Maybe your code is simple enough that it doesn't matter if it happens in a weird order. But since you're breaking people's assumptions about how the render process works, it makes it possible to introduce tricky bugs. By using useImperativeHandle, you make this component's ref work the same as all other refs, and get all the features i mentioned above.

Comment: It it combines the functionality of multiple hooks in one?
As even for the "timing" part we can use the useLayoutEffect ?

Comment: `useLayoutEffect` won't help. Layout effects run at the same time that normal effects run. The only thing different about a layout effect is that if you set state, the render that results will be done synchronously. If you use effects to update the ref, you're doing it too late. And if you do it during rendering, you're doing it too early.